# Compatibility between iOS7 and iOS6 after publication

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

My application was accepted by Apple yesterday. During the process I selected iOS6 and later for target but in the AppStore my application is marking iOS7 and later. I'm a beginner with iOS app and it's my first application which it's publicate to the store.

During the development I selected iOS7 as deployment target and I just want to know how must I do for make my application compatible iOS6 with iTunes Connect ? Is it enough to change deployment target to iOS6 in XCode ?

Is it enough to send an update in iTunes Connect or need I send a new application ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply update your target's "Deployment Target" to iOS 6.0 or 6.1 and submit an update. Of course you should thoroughly test under iOS 6 first.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to recomppile your application targeting 6.0 and send it back to apple as an Update which would mean a full review.